# selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

very new to python and hoping to gain from your experience here, when using chrome (Developer Tools/console) this command works I am choosing option #1 on a pull down menu.

```js
 document.getElementById("Locations").selectedIndex = 1
 onEntitySelectChange(document.getElementById("Locations"))
```

but when I convert this to my python using the following I get my error.

```js
driver.execute_script(f'vars element = 
  document.getElementById("Locations").selectedIndex="1");')
   
driver.execute_script(f'vars element = 
  onEntitySelectChange(document.getElementById("Locations"));')
```

ERROR:

```
in check_response    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Unexpected identifier
```

I have tried different inputs by removing "1" to just 1 removing the ';' but nothing seems to help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no identifier called vars in javascript or jquery.

user var instead of vars:

```
driver.execute_script(f'var element = 
      document.getElementById("Locations").selectedIndex="2";')
```